Hijab is not mandatory? If it is, what strong evidence is there?
Why do most people think hijab is mandatory in Islam even though the verses of the hijab in the Quran can be interpreted differently by scholars

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the stack exchange model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

assalam alaikom
Quran 24:31 and 33:59 instruct women to cover their adornment and to draw their outer garments around them, which is commonly understood as a command to wear the hijab. The Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) also reinforced modesty through his sayings, such as:
"When a woman reaches puberty, it is not appropriate for her to display any part of her body except her face and hands." (Sunan Abu Dawood)
ALLAH KNOW BEST
